# is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment> at invariant (history.ts:48

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to make privateRoute on React. I want to control user roles and users can't access every components. But i got an error like that ;

> [ProtectedRoute] is not a  component. All component children of
>  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

and here my routes ;

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, roles }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();

    if (!currentUser || (roles && !roles.includes(currentUser.role))) {
        return <NotFound />;
    }

    return children;
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <AuthProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
                        <Route
                            path="/adminanasayfa"
                            element={
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <ProtectedRoute roles={['admin']}>
                                        <AdminPage />
                                    </ProtectedRoute>
                                </React.Fragment>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/karaliste"
                            element={
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <ProtectedRoute roles={['admin']}>
                                        <AddBlackListCar />
                                    </ProtectedRoute>
                                </React.Fragment>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/misafirarac"
                            element={
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <ProtectedRoute roles={['admin']}>
                                        <AddGuestCar />
                                    </ProtectedRoute>
                                </React.Fragment>
                            }
                        />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </AuthProvider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

i tried to change Routes but i couldn't

Comment: I am expecting the error is coming from the `return children;` from the ProtectedRoute component. 
Just to verify, `return null` instead of `return children` and see if the issue goes away. If that is the issue, then inspect the components provided inside ProtectedRoute ie `AdminPage`, `AddBlackListCar`, `AddGuestCar`.

Also `<React.Fragment>` provided as wrapper to `ProtectedRoute` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think your return from ProtectedRoute isn't quite right. Try changing it to:

```
return <>{ children }</>
```

The reason is that the type of children is a ReactNode which includes types that are not allowed as return types from a React component, such as `undefined`. By wrapping children in a fragment the return type always becomes an `Element`, resulting in the component always being valid, no matter what children you pass.